# Make Compass order sprites in a consistent way

Tags: css, jquery-ui, sass, compass-sass

How can I make Compass order sprites in a consistent way, so I can have a seperate sheet for hover states?

I am using the sprite sheet tools of Compass like this:

```
@import "ui-icon/*.png";
@include all-ui-icon-sprites;
```

Which makes a nice sprite sheet like: {

```
.ui-icon-add {
  background-position: 0 -5344px; }

.ui-icon-alert {
  background-position: 0 -2352px; }

...etc...
```

But if I switch out my source sprites for the hover color, it reoreders the generated sheet:

```
.ui-icon-add {
  background-position: 0 -5376px; }

.ui-icon-alert {
  background-position: 0 -2320px; }

...etc...
```

I am using hover states like this (based off jQuery UI):

```
.ui-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('ui-icons.png');
}

.ui-state-hover .ui-icon {
    background-image: url('ui-icons-hover.png');
}
```

But because Compass isn't consistent, the icons are different when hovered.

*(I know Compass supports the `_hover` suffix, but I would much rather it generate them like jQuery UI does.)*

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the magic variable:

```
$ui-icon-sprite-layout: horizontal;
```

For both of your icon sprites. In my experience, horizontal is the only layout mode that generates two sprites with the same icons in the same order every time.

See also this Compass issue on GitHub: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/690

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `@each` loop to create your mappings the way you want them. The downside is that it requires you to follow a naming convention of `sprite` and `hover-sprite`, as well as manually editing the `$icons` variable.

**Directory Structure**

```
├── ui-icon
│   ├── add.png
│   ├── alert.png
│   ├── hover-add.png
│   └── hover-alert.png
└── ui-icon-s38eb55a811.png
```

**SCSS**

```
import "compass/utilities/sprites";

@import "ui-icon/*.png";
$icons:   add alert;

  @each $icon in $icons {
    .ui-icon-#{$icon} {
      @include ui-icon-sprite($icon);
    }
    .ui-icon-hover-#{$icon}{
      @include ui-icon-sprite("hover-" + $icon)
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-icon-add {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.ui-icon-hover-add {
  background-position: 0 -64px;
}

.ui-icon-alert {
  background-position: 0 -32px;
}

.ui-icon-hover-alert {
  background-position: 0 -96px;
}
```

Comment: Manually editing the `$icons` variable is not ideal as I have many hundreds of icons.